# Detecting if a class exists in CSS to apply style to another element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Here is some CSS:

```
/* on a laptop probably */
@media only screen and (pointer:fine) and (max-device-height: 620px) {
    #root:has(.projects) ~ body {
        overflow: auto; /* ig let them scroll to see */
    }
}
```

Here is what I expect: when we are on a laptop `(pointer: fine)` and the height of the window is `620px` or less, if `#root` has `.projects` under it (we are on the projects page) then set `overflow: auto` to let them scroll the page (because the projects page's height is 620px).

I know the mistake is here:

```
#root:has(.projects) ~ body
```

Why is this not working, and how can I do what I want to do?

Comment: "_if #root has .projects under it" Do you mean the class is applied on root, or on one of its descendants?

Comment: If `.projects` is a descendant of `#root` and we are on a laptop, with the height `<= 620px`, then I want scrolling to be on: `body { overflow: auto; }`

Comment: `#root` feels like a typo with `:root`, which would select the `<html>` node. But then, in an HTML document, the only element on which you could use the general sibling element combinator (`~`) to target `<body>` is the `<head>` element. So it feels even this combinator is wrong. Now, if we assume that `.projects` will be a descendant of the `<body>`, you could make it much simpler with `body:has(.projects) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

The `~` selector in CSS is used to select elements that are siblings. In React, `body` is parent of `#root` and the `~` selector will not work as expected. You can use something like

```
body:has(#root .projects) {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

It targets the `body` element if it contains an element with the class `.projects` that is a descendant of an element with the id `#root`.

Desktop
[image: Desktop]

Mobile
[image: Mobile]

Comment: This is so weird, this doesn't work with the media query i had ...

Comment: @user129393192 so, the media query works and the code I provided works individually. However, when combined together, they don't work?

Comment: Yes, refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76625501/changing-the-style-of-an-element-when-the-screen-size-is-smaller-than-620px-and/76625579#76625579). The current answer states that even the  `has` selector shouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, I think you have two problems here. First, `:has()` is only supported in some latest versions of browsers. You can check its compatibility on `canIuse` and decide whether to use it or not based on your target browser support. Second, how did you test it? I tested it in Google Chrome, and it seems to work well. You can see the updated image in my response.

Comment: I tested it and I saw that it updated in the dev console, but I found that it still did **not** permit scrolling even when the screen was < 620 px.

Comment: If you can say how to do that ^ I will definitely accept your answer. That was the end goal here.