# Changing the style of an element when the screen size is smaller than 620px and another element exists

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, user-interface

Here is some CSS:

```
/* on a laptop probably */
@media only screen and (pointer:fine) and (max-device-height: 620px) {
    body:has(#root .projects) {
        overflow: auto; /* ig let them scroll to see */
    }
}
```

but it is not working (this is a React app).

The intention is that when `#root .projects` exists, then set `overflow: auto` on the body (typical is `hidden`) so that users can scroll. This specifically when the device-height is < 620 px (projects is centered and height of 620px) and on a desktop (don't want this on mobile).

What's wrong and how can I instead accomplish this? I would be open to JS or CSS.

Answer (score 0):

has selector is not supported in major web browsers,it was removed in most of the browsers due to performance and implementation challenges.

Currently, there is no direct equivalent or alternative to the :has selector in CSS. It is not possible to select an element based on its descendants or content using CSS alone. You would need to use JavaScript or libraries like jQuery to achieve this kind of selection and manipulation.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const rootProjectsElement = document.querySelector('#root .projects');
    const bodyElement = document.body;

    const handleWindowResize = () => {
      if (rootProjectsElement && window.innerHeight < 620) {
        bodyElement.classList.add('overflow-auto');
      } else {
        bodyElement.classList.remove('overflow-auto');
      }
    };

    handleWindowResize(); // Check on initial render

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your component's content */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

```css
.overflow-auto {
  overflow: auto;
}
```